# WinAmp: Enqueue folders from Command Line?

Tags: winamp

Trying to simplify a basic WinAMP operation, I know it's something very simple but I can't find anyone who's done it (I have found something about enqueuing a single file from a command line, but I think that required an actual programming component).

Is there a quick and easy way to enqueue a folder to Winamp from a command-line or BAT file? (Reason I ask--there are six different folders with updating content that I add to my playlist, and when I want to refresh it I have to do them all by hand; looking for an easier way to go about it.)

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure!

Piece of cake.

You want to use the command:
`"C:\path_to_winamp\winamp.exe" /ADD "folder_to_enqueue"`

If I were doing this often, I would probably put winamp in my path or find another clever way of spawning it.

How on earth did I know this? (you might ask).

- I installed winamp (normally, I just use a portable copy)
- After running it once, it offered to integrate into the explorer.
- I looked at the HKCR registry under both "Folder" and "Directory" (it could be in either).
- I found the key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Winamp.Enqueue\command` which shows the command to enqueue "stuff".
- The (default) key looks like this: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Winamp\winamp.exe" /ADD "%1"`

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!!! (Glad I'm not the only one that wanted to do this!)

Comment: Related question: is there a way to clear the playlist (the equivalent of CTRL+N with the playlist window selected) the same way?

Comment: Now you got me!  I ripped apart the exe and found the command line params.  Try running it with `/CLEAR` and see what happens.  I can't test it here but I did indeed find that as a valid command line switch.  It also looks like there is a way to pass commands to the player with `/COMMAND=command_here` but I can't tell what those might be.  I will update my answer if I have a chance to figure it out when I get home.

Comment: That does indeed do the trick! This is awesomely helpful!

Comment: Check this out:  https://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/Winamp_command_line  don't know if it is still valid.

Comment: That's really cool!